# Ajax call to inline grid text field from block grid

Tags: ajax, magento2.4.5, product-grid, sort-by-position

I have created the block grid in admin product edit page section, I have added a text field in that grid column using below addcolumn method.

```
$this->addColumn(
            'position',
            [
                'header' => __('Position'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'position',
                'editable' => true,
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
            ]
        );
```

Now I want to add an Ajax call when the admin user tries to change the inline state,
[image]

When the admin user wants to change the position from row number three to row number one, at that moment I want an ajax call in the text field of the position column.

can I someone help me to how to add Ajax call in block grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but you can follow this steps may be help:
1). If custom grid you can define require-config.js and with the help of it you can do it.
2). In core you can simple add JS file in layout.
For more information follow this: [Add JS in adminhtml](https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-custom-js-file-in-magento-2-admin-panel/)
3). After that capture onclick and do the needful.

Comment: Hi Aniket, I have already tried this solution but I unable to get values on the enter key. added phtml and tried with script.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: {
    'use strict';
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("input[name='position']").keypress(function(event){
   var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if(keycode == '13') {
    var numItems = $('.col-id-position').length;
    var movePosition = this.value;
    var existingPosition = $(this).closest("td").find("span.admin__grid-control-value").text();
    if(movePosition > numItems){
    alert('Please put the value in between of 1 to '+numItems);
   }
          }
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });

Comment: I have created block and added template file and testing purpose added hello message, template work fine.
tried to add above script in that template but simple alert hello is not working on enter key..

same script I have tried to create normal php form with html and there this script work fine.

due to text limit I have not added script and require function in above script

let me know if I miss anything, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Also checked there is no any error message in console

Comment: Please add code in answer? Have you check your JS is loaded on page or not? 1st try with simple alert or console.log on click of any main button class.

Comment: it's big mistake from my side,
yesterday I have checked that, there is couple of file I have created in same name with different folders,and written code was in another file ;) Now I am able to render the Javascript, :) thanks for your support,.

Comment: Happy to help!!

Comment: just another query after Ajax success I am trying to bind data through controller to block, so is that possible to create layout in controller and call to block.

I have tried this but block data not render on Ajax success but ajax works fine.

$resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
return $resultRaw->setContents(
   $this->layoutFactory->create()->createBlock(
    'Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Marketing\Content\Edit\Tab\Product',
    'marketing.product.grid'
   )->toHtml()
  );

Comment: You can create layout in controller but will not work in AJAX, to bind data you must use jQuery or data binding in JS(magento 2) https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html
It will also help in frontend whenever JS bundling is enable.
Thanks for accepting answer!!